# Generalize a simple Phone Number Regex

Tags: python, regex

This is a simple example to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Hypothetically, say I want to write a function that takes in an unprocessed phone number string (examples below) and returns a specific format of the string.

```
"123-4567" --> "123-4567"

"123.4567" --> "123-4567"

"1234567" --> "123-4567"
```

I can use the regex pattern "^[0-9]{3}[-.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$" to match the 3 possibilities but if it matches, I still have to check which type it matches.

```
def process(original):
    if re.match("^[0-9]{3}[-.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$", original):
        # Maybe some other stuff I only want to put once
        if re.match("^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$" original):
            # Stuff
        elif re.match("^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4}$", original):
            # Stuff
        elif re.match("^[0-9]{7}$", original):
            # Stuff
```

This seems to have more redundancy than needed.

I could skip the outer `if` but then there might be things I'd have to redundantly copy/paste, as indicated. Also, that wouldn't solve all of the redundancy issues.

I'm aware I could just check `if '-' in original` or `if '.' in original`, or also just if the length is 8 instead of 7.

My question is there a more general solution that doesn't introduce redundancy or other issues.

Comment: What if you strip out all non-digit characters, check that there are 7 characters left and then format those as needed?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can replace [0-9] with "\d" and replace {0,1} with "?".
If you put "[-.]" in a group then with this code you can see what your number matched with:

Code:

```
import re

pattern = "^\d{3}([-.])?\d{4}$"

numbers = ["123-4567", "123.4567", "1234567"]

for number in numbers:
    m = re.match(pattern, number)
    if m.group(1) == '-':
        pass
    elif m.group(1) == '.':
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can strip out the non digit characters and then insert a dash:

```
semiformatted = "".join(c for c in unformatted if c.isdigit())
if 7 == len(semiformatted):
    formatted = semiformatted[:3] + "-" + semiformatted[3:]
else:
    # Or however you'd like to handle bad numbers
    raise Exception(f"This is bad input: {unformatted}")
```

It's largely non-material, but if you want to use a regex to strip out the characters you can do this:

```
semiformatted = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", unformatted)
```

Comment: This doesnt work I think. Consider "12-34567". Edit: I realize I didn't give this example in my original post. Your solution definitely does work on the examples I gave

Comment: How would you like to choose the index for the dash? In the example `1234567` it seems clear you want the dash after the 3rd character - but maybe that's not the case? Is this a case where you want to use `replace()`?